# KQL Top-Nested with Count of Matching Rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a dataset with source and location data. I'm trying to get the top location by source, along with total hits for that path.

I've tried using summarize, but I only want the top 3 sources for each destination.

```
TransportData
| summarize TotalVisits=count() by Destination, Source
```

I've also tried using top-nested, but this leaves me without the total hits for each path.

```
TransportData
| top-nested 50 of Destination by count(), top-nested 3 of Source by count()
```

Comment: What exactly are you missing with the second query?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using `partition`. Note that partition caps at 64 items, so it will not work for all datasets.

```
TransportData
| partition by Destination
(
    top 3 by Source
)
| summarize TotalTrips=count()*SampleRate by Destination, Source
```